# How do I change the color of toc_float bars in Rmarkdown html using CSS

Tags: html, css, r-markdown

Can't find the attribute. I just want to change it so it's not blue anymore.

Comment: what is your setup? Please look to the [how to ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.